# след от движения фигур по экрану, с чем он связан, почему он есть

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/JsJx7/1/

код по ссылке :

```
`function anim(canvas, fps, clear) 
{
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var interval = null;
    var update = null;
    var draw = null;

    this.update = function(func) {
        update = func;
    };

    this.draw = function(func) {
        draw = func;
    };

    var step = function() {
        if (clear) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        if (update !== null) {
            update();
        }
        if (draw !== null) {
            draw();
        }
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };

    this.play = function() {
        if (draw !== null) {
            draw();
        }
        interval = setInterval(step, 1000 / fps);
    };
}

function circle(x, y, r) 
{
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
    this.r = r; 
    this.draw = function(context, color, globalAlpha) 
    {
        context.globalAlpha = globalAlpha; // "прозрачность"
        context.fillStyle = color; // цвет заливки
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.fill();
    };
}

function rect(x, y, width, height) 
{
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
    this.width = width; // ширина
    this.height = height; // высота
       this.draw = function(context, color, globalAlpha) {
        context.globalAlpha = globalAlpha; // "прозрачность"
        context.fillStyle = color; // цвет заливки
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
}

function init() 
{
    var screen = new rect(0, 0, 320, 320);
    var ball1 = new circle(178, 25, 25);
    var ball3 = new circle(25, 150, 25);
    var vX1 = 5;
    var vY1 = 5;
    var vX3 = 5;
    var vY3 = 5;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("example");
    canvas.width = screen.width;
    canvas.height = screen.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var game = new anim(canvas, 30, false);
    game.draw(function() {
        screen.draw(context, "#000", 0.5);
        ball1.draw(context, "#f00", 1);
        ball3.draw(context, "#fff", 1);
    });

    game.update(function() {
        if (ball1.y - ball1.r < 0 || ball1.y + ball1.r > 320) // соприкосновение с "полом" и "потолком" холста
        {
            vY1 = -vY1;
        }
        if (ball1.x - ball1.r < 0 || ball1.x + ball1.r > 320) // соприкосновение с левой и правой "стенкой" холста 
        {
            vX1 = -vX1;
        }



         if (ball3.y - ball3.r < 0 || ball3.y + ball3.r > 320) // соприкосновение с "полом" и "потолком" холста
        {
            vY3 = -vY3;
        }
        if (ball3.x - ball3.r < 0 || ball3.x + ball3.r > 320) // соприкосновение с левой и правой "стенкой" холста 
        {
            vX3 = -vX3;
        }

// условие соприкосновения шаров друг с другом               
        if ( Math.abs(ball1.x  - ball3.x) + Math.abs(ball1.y - ball3.y) <= 50)
        {

            vX1 = -vX1;
            vX3 = -vX3;
            vY1 = -vY1;
            vY3 = -vY3;

       }

        ball1.x += vX1;
        ball1.y += vY1;
        ball3.x += vX3;
        ball3.y += vY3;

    });

    screen.draw(context, "#000", 1);
    ball1.draw(context, "#f00", 1);
    ball3.draw(context, "#fff", 1);

    var click = false;
    // по шелчку мыши останавливаем обновление холста,
    // если холст остановлен продолжаем анимацию
    canvas.onclick = function() {
        if (!click) {
            click = true;
            game.play();
        } else {
            click = false;
            game.stop();
        }
    };
}

init();`
```

Если нажмете на картинку , то шары начнут двигаться и оставлять за собой след. В код я не вникал, синтаксис javascript не знаком. Запуская подобное, написанное на java на операционке Андроид, такого следа нет. В каких то случаях он нужен для изящности , а где то наоборот лишний. Так с чем связано его появление? Какие то особенности javascript ? или монитора?  В java система такая:  игровая сцена залилась фоновым рисунком, нарисовали объекты, изменили координаты объектов, залили фон и снова нарисовали. А как тут?  Может есть в библиотека javascript код , который намеренно создает этот след ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JsJx7/11/ вот так очистка будет каждый кадр и следа не будет

Comment: Из-за того, что фон прорисовывается с прозрачностью и предыдущие слои через него просвечиваются до поры до времени. Поэтому вы видите где-то 3-4 предыдущих слоя, но хуже, и кажется что шары размывает. Достаточно закомментировать `context.globalAlpha = globalAlpha` в функции `rect` и размытие исчезнет http://jsfiddle.net/ngz8ssjb/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

След появляется из за того, что фон каждый кадр заливается черным цветом с альфа каналом 0.5

```
game.draw(function() {
    screen.draw(context, "#000", 0.5); // Вот эти ребята
    ball1.draw(context, "#f00", 1);
    ball3.draw(context, "#fff", 1);
});
```

За счет этого предыдущие шары исчезают не сразу, а постепенно.

Прогрессбар меняет длину следа:

```js
function anim(canvas, fps) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var interval = null;
    var update = null;
    var draw = null;

    this.update = function(func) {
        update = func;
    };

    this.draw = function(func) {
        draw = func;
    };

    var step = function() {
        if (update !== null) {
            update();
        }
        if (draw !== null) {
            draw();
        }
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };

    this.play = function() {
        if (draw !== null) {
            draw();
        }
        interval = setInterval(step, 1000 / fps);
    };
}

function circle(x, y, r) 
{
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
    this.r = r; 
    this.draw = function(context, color, globalAlpha) 
    {
        context.globalAlpha = globalAlpha; // "прозрачность"
        context.fillStyle = color; // цвет заливки
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.fill();
    };
}

function rect(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
    this.width = width; // ширина
    this.height = height; // высота
       this.draw = function(context, color, globalAlpha) {
        context.globalAlpha = globalAlpha; // "прозрачность"
        context.fillStyle = color; // цвет заливки
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
}

var screen = new rect(0, 0, 220, 220);
var ball1 = new circle(178, 25, 25);
var vX1 = 5;
var vY1 = 5;
var canvas = document.getElementById("example");
canvas.width = screen.width;
canvas.height = screen.height;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var game = new anim(canvas, 30);

game.draw(function() {
    screen.draw(context, "#000", range.value);
    ball1.draw(context, "#f00", 1);
});

game.update(function() {
    if (ball1.y - ball1.r < 0 || ball1.y + ball1.r > 220) // соприкосновение с "полом" и "потолком" холста
    {
        vY1 = -vY1;
    }
    if (ball1.x - ball1.r < 0 || ball1.x + ball1.r > 220) // соприкосновение с левой и правой "стенкой" холста 
    {
        vX1 = -vX1;
    }

    ball1.x += vX1;
    ball1.y += vY1;
});

screen.draw(context, "#000", 1);
ball1.draw(context, "#f00", 1);

game.play();
```

```html
<input id='range' type='range' min=0 max=1 step=.01 /><br/>
<canvas id="example"></canvas>
```